# is it possible to use DateFormatter & @DateTimeFormat together in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to configure my web app to use the @DateTimeFormat on some fields and at the same time to fall back to a default DateFormatter ( configured in the conversionService) for the other date fields not having this annotation. I do not seem to get this working :-( any help ?

Comment: 'I do not seem to get this working': this does not seem to be enough information. Please elaborate on that, what is the concrete problem error message, etc.?

Comment: no the concrete problem is that if I configure the DateFormatter through the conversionService bean say with format dd.MM.yy **AND** at the same time have a date field annotated with dd-MM-yy then the result in the view will be dd.MM.yy and not as expected dd-MM-yy. If I remove the DateFormatter config then it works